# Bootstrap modal and BXslider not working

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bxslider

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="quickview">
  OPEN MODAL
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">BX Slider</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="bxslider">
          <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="bx-pager">
          <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/thumbs/tree_root.jpg" /></a>
          <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/thumbs/houses.jpg" /></a>
          <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/thumbs/hill_fence.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function quickView() {
  var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
    controls: false
  });
  slider.destroySlider();
  //$('#myModal').modal('show');
  slider.reloadSlider();
}
$(".quickview").on("click", quickView);
```

I have a Bootstrap modal which I'm injecting dynamic image galleries into. So fx. I have 10 links on a page, each link is containing unique data-attributes with image URLs. I am then sending these URLs into my click event, so I can use them with BXslider, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I'm reloading the BXslider within my click event, but the "mainimage" is not showing.
However, if I move the code out of the click event, it seems like it's working.

Any suggestions here?

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/marting/pen/dYNabj?editors=101

Comment: I've set up a new example, where I'm injecting image src like on the real site: http://codepen.io/marting/pen/ZbLwwx?editors=101

Comment: Soooo I just found out, that the image will appear if I resize the image. Found a bug on BXsliders Git page, so guess I'm a bit stuck from here..
https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/359

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to this, and it works like a charm

JS:

```
function quickView() {
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
    controls: false 
});
setTimeout(function() {
    slider.reloadSlider();}, 200);
}
$(".quickview").on("click", quickView);
```

See it works here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYgxOE?editors=101